# get a 2d array to write and read line by line using VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to read a txt file in a 2d array using VB.Net I can insert the msgbox on top of my first For next loop and get all the information word by word.  but if I go outside my for next loop I can not access all information My ultimate goal is to be able to say if first column = xyz GOTO Line123 and travel through the array doing this when it goes to its assigned GOTO line the it will write a new txt file with all the information in the entire row. as of now I am using a small array of 40x62 here is a look at my code below I used file.ReadAllLines(R\TxtFile.csv").Length -1 to get the length of my text file to determine the number of needed rows due to it will change frequently. MonitorIDColumn should read all that is in column 0 and then I need to use that to write the file for everything in that row. What am I doing wrong???????

```
file.ReadAllLines(R\TxtFile.csv").Length -1    
reader = New streamReader("R:\TxtFile.scv")
    Dim Linie as string 
    Dim x,y as integer
    For x = 0 to LineCount
        Linie = reader.ReadLine
        For y = 0 to 62 
        CRSFile2DArray(x,y) = Split(Linie, ",")(y)
        MsgBox(CRSFile2DArray(x,y))
        Next 'y
    Next 'x
    For x = 1 to LineCount
        For y = 0 62
        MonitorIDColumn = CRSFile2DArray(x,0)
```

Comment: Some parts of your code are missing. For example, `LineCount` is not defined anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Why are you reading the file twice?  Surely calling readalllines which returns an array of string you can iterate over to then split the contents?  There are also plenty of 3rd party tools(check nugets) that make processing csv files very simple

Comment: "What am I doing wrong???????" Missing a double quote `R\TxtFile.csv"`, expression is not assigned to anything `file.ReadAllLines(R\TxtFile.csv").Length -1`, indentation, capitalization, and spacing is not right (did you actually have this code in an IDE?), reading the file twice, using `MsgBox`, not disposing the StreamReader, `For y = 0 62`... post some code which compiles first